# Регулярное выражение не дает добавлять товар в корзину

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет. Есть регулярка, которая проверяет наименование товара и отправляет его в корзину.

```
var $product_name_rules    = '\\\.\:\-_ a-z0-9а-яА-Я()-,.!&';
```

Но вот проблема, когда есть наименование товара вот такое `Спальный гарнитур Диана 3Д\4Д` товар не попадает в корзину из за слэлша, что делать?

Comment: не продавать данный товар )

Comment: и без слэша не проходит - https://regex101.com/r/nMU8SC/2

Comment: @splash58 а должно?, это ведь не регулярка целиком, а просто набор символов, который в ней будет использован. на кой то черт налеплено экранирований только

Comment: @teran если честно, я даже этого не понял, отправил на regex, может подставит чего нормального

Comment: Используйте `preg_match('~^[\\\\.:_\sa-z0-9а-яё(),.!&-]+$~ui', $str)`